# Android theme doesn't affect anything

Tags: android, android-styles

I want every text in my app to be white.

This is what I did:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>    
</style>
```

And in the manifest I set this attribute of the `application` tag: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Why won't the text color change?

Comment: Are you already setting the colour on the `TextView`s? That would override the colour here.

Comment: Can you post your xml of textview? in TextView set "style="@style/MyTextViewStyle" and do not set textColor in TextView tag

Comment: I don't change the color manually on the text view. And I don't want to set the style directly.. I want it to be applied automatically for all text views.

Comment: The textview sets:  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" and if I remove it the font gets smaller, but the color does not change to white.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Tried that but the app theme doesn't even recognize the "android:textViewStyle"

Comment: Could you try to update the appcompat library version? I'm using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1` and it's working properly

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. Use this for your textView style

```
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>    
</style>
```

This should work.